# Kentico 6.0.42 Tools tab does not display Media Library

Tags: kentico

I have imported a site into my local Kentico CMS Desk. The export had Media Library and physical files in it. But when I log into my local CMS Desk I do not get the option of Media Library in CMS Desk - Tools option.
I am logged in as Global Administrator both during export and import and I have permission on the Media Library module to Create, Modify and Destroy in CMS Desk.
The UI Personalization for this user displays the checkbox for Media Library - Add new library.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sounds like it is the fact that you are missing UI Personalization values of the module. You should not just have Add new library. If you don't have other customizations you do a fresh install of 6.0.42 and export the whole tools module and import the whole module into your site. This will overwrite your settings to have a full clean set.

Comment: Yes, you are absolutely correct. This solved my issue. Just wondering if there is a way to configure the installation of Kentico site through a file based list of modules. Thanks for taking the time to answer my question.